# Unable to view the respective label icons in moodle after adding https

Tags: php, https, apache2, moodle

I have setup a moodle instance and made necessary changes in config.php file. In config.php file changed the domain name and moodledata path. Later i added the https certificate using certbot. Now i am unable to view the icons on my moodle instance

Comment: Removed the broken picture from the question

Answer (score 0):

As you have installed an SSL certificate now your site redirects to HTTPS instead of HTTP. As the icons used in moodle have their base URL set to HTTP the icons are missing after the upgrade. If you inspect the missing icon you might see that URL is HTTP instead of HTTPS as per SSL redirect. If that is the case all you have to do is update the base URL from HTTP to HTTPS. Similar kind of issue with a solution in a forum: https://ask.gibbonedu.org/discussion/2578/help-my-icons-have-all-gone-missing

Source: https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Configuration_file

$CFG->wwwroot   = 'https://example.com/moodle';